# R: filter a dataframe by several columns defined in a list

Tags: r, dataframe, filter

I have a dataframe which I'd like to filter. I have the column names of those columns by which I want to filter the data defined in a list, so I'd like to used them in some kind of `dplyr::filter` function to filter the rows. The list fo column names is large and it can change under different conditions when I execute my code, so I can't define the column names one by one in the `filter` function.

Here's an example of my dataframe:

```
       Day     Element   Column_A    Column_B   Column_C
2020-01-01       elem1          1           0          0
2020-01-02       elem2          0           1          0
2020-01-03       elem3          0           0          0
2020-01-04       elem4          0           0          0
```

And the list of column names would be `c("Column_A","Column_B","Column_C")`

I want to filter it by deleting any row with a 1:

```
       Day     Element   Column_A    Column_B   Column_C
2020-01-03       elem3          0           0          0
2020-01-04       elem4          0           0          0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `rowSums` here:

```r
names <- c("Column_A", "Column_B", "Column_C")
df[rowSums(df[names]) == 0, ]

         Day Element Column_A Column_B Column_C
3 2020-01-03   elem3        0        0        0
4 2020-01-04   elem4        0        0        0
```

**Data:**

```
df <- data.frame(Day=c("2020-01-01", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-03", "2020-01-04"),
                 Element=c("elem1", "elem2", "elem3", "elem4"),
                 Column_A=c(1,0,0,0),
                 Column_B=c(0,1,0,0),
                 Column_C=c(0,0,0,0))
```

This phrases a matching row as any row which has a sum of zero across all the data columns.  I assume here that you don't have to cater for possible negative values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `if_all` in `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)

cols <- c("Column_A","Column_B","Column_C")
df %>% filter(if_all(all_of(cols), ~. == 0))

#         Day Element Column_A Column_B Column_C
#1 2020-01-03   elem3        0        0        0
#2 2020-01-04   elem4        0        0        0
```

With `if_any` :

```
df %>% filter(!if_any(all_of(cols), ~. == 1))
```